# how to write to csv in python?

Tags: python, file, csv

I have a row:

```
row = {'A':'valueA', 'B':'valueB', 'C':'valueC'}
```

Basically I want to open a new `csv` file and write each value in its column, e.g.

```
 ---------------------------
|   A     |  B     |   C    |
 ---------------------------
|  ValueA | ValueB | ValueC |
 ---------------------------
```

I am doing this:

```
def OandWtonew(filename, row):
with open('Ouput1.csv', 'wt') as csvfile:
    fileout = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    fileout.writerow(row)
```

but the output I am getting is:

```
 --------------------------------------------
|   A           |  B           |  C          |
 --------------------------------------------
|  'A':'valueA' | 'B':'valueB' | 'C':'valueC'|
 --------------------------------------------
```

All replies are much appreciated :)

Comment: Why aren't you using a DictWriter?

Comment: @coldspeed Off topic, I know but 100k !! congrats. And I see you found a job at Google (weren't you looking for one?)

Comment: Looks like you should use `csv.dictwriter` and not `csv.writer`

Comment: I don't see how you are getting that output with that code.

Comment: @JoeIddon Thanks! Also, yes, an internship. Months ago, in fact. Actually, I've finished my internship, so I need to update that title. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 3):

Since the data is a dictionary, [`csv.DictWriter()`](https://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) may be the most straightforward way to do it. 
Just make sure the list of header values are in the original order, in this case [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) may be the easiest:

```
with open('Ouput1.csv', 'wt') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = sorted(row.keys())  # needs to be the first line in correct order
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow(row)             # writes corresponding value for key in header
```

[image: CSV view in Excel]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv()` to easily write to a csv:

```
import pandas as pd

row = {'A':'valueA', 'B':'valueB', 'C':'valueC'}

#Convert dictionary to a pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame().append(row, ignore_index=True)

# check output
df
    A       B       C
0   valueA  valueB  valueC

# Save to a csv file
df.to_csv('Ouput1.csv',index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

`row` is of type `dict`. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter):

```
import csv
with open('names.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Baked', 'last_name': 'Beans'})
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Lovely', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Wonderful', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
```